# Map distortion and the difference between the Orthographic and Stereographic Azimuthal projection

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, azimuth

I am new to the topic of maps and distortions and am a bit confused about the effects of conform and no-conform maps. Taking as an example the Azimuthal projection: I have read that with the Orthographic projection as well as the Stereographic projection I can measure a correct angle from the poles against the Meridians.

So far so good, then it is stated that the benefit of the Stereographic projection is that, I can also measure all angles between two points and not only from the poles.

However, when I checked the relation between several points within these projections the measured angle seemed to be the same. So I used QGIS to see the effect and got this:

Stereographic projection (+proj=stere +lat_0=90 +lon_0=0)
[image: Stereographic projection]

And this:
Orthographic projection (+proj=ortho +lat_0=90 +lon_0=0)
[image: Orthographic projection]

In the first projection, the measured angle was -91,738° and in the second projection, it was -92,077°, so we got a pretty small difference which is also probably to my inaccuracy in using the same points on the map.

Since it has been stated that the Orthographic is not useable for measuring the distance between two points where one of them is not the pole - and the Stereographic project is usable for that I would have expected a bigger difference in the angles. - Or am I confusing something here?

Comment: `I can also measure all angles between two points`-- I'm pretty sure no flat projection can do that per the Riemann Mapping Theorem

Comment: Hi Barry, I have looked it up and in most places, it is described that it "preserves (or represents) angles" (source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereographic_map_projection#Properties). 

However here I found a description, which covers at best what I mean: "and the angle between two lines on the sphere is the same as the angle between their images in the plane. A projection that preserves angles is called a conformal projection. “(source: http://www.geom.uiuc.edu/docs/doyle/mpls/handouts/node33.html)

Comment: My mistake. I reread https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_mapping_theorem and it only says you can't conformally map the entire sphere, but you can conformally map portions of the sphere, as long as at least two points are excluded. I should've known that since I believe the Mercator projection is conformal too though it may only be locally conformal

Comment: No problem! But what you stated is quite interesting, too: "believe the Mercator projection is conformal too though it may only be locally conform" my understanding was that the Mercator projection does preseve the angles while is streches the shape ",east-west scale is the same as the north-south scale"(http://wiki.gis.com/wiki/index.php/Mercator_projection). Does not not make the projection conformal everywhere and not only in the area of the "0" line where the zylinder hits the map? If this is wrong, until wihch are is the angle preserving correct (e. g. 50 % from the "0" line)?